# Expressão regular pelo índice da string

Tags: r, regex

Considere esta variável:

```
x <- c('horccaeon', 'coleon', 'volues', 'mol', 'nao', 'tom', 'nada', 
'auio', 'aqoio')
```

Eu usei a seguinte `regex` para extrair as strings com a segunda letra `o`:

```
library(tidyverse)

str_detect(string = x, regex(pattern = '.o[^o]'))

[1] "horccaeon" "coleon"    "volues"    "mol"       "tom"
```

Funciona, mas **eu sei** que isto está errado.

Também tentei usar o *lookahead*:

```
str_subset(string = x, regex(pattern = '.(?=o)'))

[1] "horccaeon" "coleon"    "volues"    "mol"       "nao"       "tom"       "auio"     
[8] "aqoio"
```

Mas retorna tudo que contém `o`, não apenas a segunda letra.

**Considere o inverso agora**: retirar as strings com a antepenúltima letra `o`. Não consegui pensar em uma `regex` pra isso.

Assim:

- como ajustar uma `regex` para que ela dê *match* com as posições/ índices da string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se quer que a letra `o` seja a segunda letra da string, pode usar o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`, que indica o início da string:

```
str_subset(string = x, regex(pattern = '^.o'))
```

Assim, temos o início da string (`^`), seguido de um caractere qualquer (o ponto, que significa "[qualquer caractere, exceto quebras de linha](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)"), seguido da letra `o`. O resultado, neste caso, é:

```
[1] "horccaeon" "coleon"    "volues"    "mol"       "tom"
```

Repare que as strings `'nao`, `'auio'` e `'aqoio'` ficam de fora, pois a letra `o` não é o segundo caractere (a string `'nada'` também não é retornada porque sequer tem um `o`).

---

Já para verificar se a antepenúltima letra é um `o`, pode usar o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$`, que indica o final da string:

```
str_subset(string = x, regex(pattern = 'o.{2}$'))
```

Agora temos a letra `o`, seguida de [dois caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) (`.{2}`), seguida do final da string (`$`). O resultado é:

```
[1] "aqoio"
```

---

De maneira geral, você deve usar `^` se quiser verificar se a letra `o` é a enésima letra do início, ou `$` se quiser verificar se ela está X posições do final. Ex:

- `^o` - começa com `o`
- `^.{3}o` - a quarta letra é `o` (pois tem 3 caracteres quaisquer antes)
- `o$` - termina com `o`
- `o.{3}$` - tem a letra `o`, mais 3 caracteres, e o final da string

Claro que se quiser, pode trocar o ponto por algo mais específico (como por exemplo `[a-z]`, assim a regex só considera a letra `o` caso tenha letras antes ou depois - se usar o ponto, pode ter qualquer caractere, inclusive não-alfanuméricos).

---

Apenas para explicar as suas regex, nenhuma delas usa os marcadores `^` e `$`, o que quer dizer que o padrão pode ser encontrado no meio da string (assim, não garante que a letra `o` será sempre a segunda ou antepenúltima, ou qualquer outra posição específica, [veja](https://ideone.com/TBBHFE)).

`.o[^o]` é qualquer caractere, seguido de `o`, seguido de um caractere [que não seja](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `o`. Isso quer dizer se tiver algo como `'zoo'`, [ela não pega](https://regex101.com/r/eOLFr4/1/), pois depois do `o` deve ter um caractere que não é `o`. Além disso, obriga a ter algo depois do `o`, excluindo palavras com duas letras, como `'do'` ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/eOLFr4/2/)).

`.(?=o)` é qualquer caractere que tenha um `o` logo depois, então na prática é qualquer string com pelo menos dois caracteres, em que a letra `o` tem um caractere antes (mas não necessariamente a letra `o` será o segundo caractere, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/eOLFr4/3/)).

Comment: `regex` só com muito treino mesmo. Eu sei desses operadores mas não consegui aplicá-los. Obrigado de novo.

Comment: Como eu usaria o `regex(pattern = '.(?=o)')` se "o" na verdade fosse um vetor ?

Answer (score 0):

Uai cê tá ligado no grep? Ele possui uma flag chamada (value = false), se ela estiver false ele retorna os índices, se true ele retorna os elementos selecionados de x; Não se preocupe em setar a flag, por padrão ela já é false.

Testa aí:

```
x <- c('horccaeon', 'coleon', 'volues', 'mol', 'nao', 'tom', 'nada', 'auio', 'aqoio')
p <- c('[^o]')
sapply(p , function(y) grep(y,x))
```